# Adding point shapefile to map shuts down program

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, corrupt

I am trying to add a point file that I have used before to a map.  Every time I add it the program (ArcGIS) crashes.  I can add other files, including the same data for a different year, but this specific file crashes the program, so I assume there is something wrong with the file. It would be very difficult to recreate the file, so I need to diagnose what might be wrong and then repair the file...if possible.

Comment: What software did you use to create the shapefile?  What datatypes are present in the file? (nil, point, poly, area)  Do some of the features have Z values or measures?  Is the .dbf file valid?

Comment: Can you access any attributes of the point shapefile programmatically?  If you are familiar with python, check to see if the number of features matches the number of records.

Comment: Geocoded in ArcMap a couple of years ago.  Points. No Z values. I can open the .dbf in SPSS.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things to try:

1. If the point shp table has coordinate fields you could re-generate the shp from the coordinates
2. Try using QGIS as your data viewer, it seems to handle corrupt shapefiles better than ArcMap (does not crash as easily).  It should allow you to see the features within the shapefile that are not corrupted
3. You may also try the [Repair Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000) tool within ArcToolbox

Comment: I'd add to artwork's #2 above, if you can open it in QGIS, do a Save As from there and save it to a new shapefile.

Comment: I don't know what QGIS is.  I will look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the shapefile to investigate?